# Prompt the user to authorise the application to share types in HealthKit

Tags: objective-c, ios8, healthkit

When first calling `requestAuthorizationToShareTypes:readTypes:completion:` of the `HKHealthStore` with the set of `HKQuantityType` I want permissions to, I can see this modal view requesting authorization from the user to read and share every type of object for which the application may require access.

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to prompt the user this modal view, besides the first time i'm calling: `requestAuthorizationToShareTypes:readTypes:completion:`.

I tried calling the `requestAuthorizationToShareTypes:readTypes:completion:` every time with the same set but after the first call its not prompting anymore. When trying to change the set with a new type that wasn't there before I can successfully prompt this screen, but I don't think calling this method each time with a new `HKQuantityType` in the set is the right way (as there is a limit to the amount of types exists).

Is it even possible?

Thanks for any help whatsoever.

**UPDATE**

I'll add some code snippet of the call:

```
 [self.healthStore  requestAuthorizationToShareTypes:writeDataTypes readTypes:readDataTypes completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        if (!success) {
            NSLog(@"You didn't allow HealthKit to access these read/write data types. The error was: %@.", error);
            return;
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Update the user interface based on the current user's health information.
        });
    }];
```

where `writeDataTypesz` and `readDataTypes` are `NSSet` returned from the following methods:

```
// Returns the types of data that I want to write to HealthKit.
- (NSSet *)dataTypesToWrite
{
    HKQuantityType *heightType = [HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeight];
    HKQuantityType *weightType = [HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMass];

    return [NSSet setWithObjects: heightType, weightType, nil];
}

// Returns the types of data that I want to read from HealthKit.
- (NSSet *)dataTypesToRead
{
    HKQuantityType *heightType = [HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeight];
    HKQuantityType *weightType = [HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMass];
    HKCharacteristicType *birthdayType = [HKCharacteristicType characteristicTypeForIdentifier:HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierDateOfBirth];
    HKCharacteristicType *biologicalSex = [HKCharacteristicType characteristicTypeForIdentifier:HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierBiologicalSex];
    return [NSSet setWithObjects:heightType,weightType,birthdayType,biologicalSex, nil];
}
```

Changing the set to include *NEW* types each time I call `requestAuthorizationToShareTypes:readTypes:completion:` results in opening this view with all the types that I ever asked permissions to (not necessarily in this specific call):
[image: screenshot of the view that the user sees when prompt for permissions]

Comment: Just like with location, contact, etc.. access the system will only ask it once's from your app. After this you will have to detect the authorization state yourself and ask the user to go to the settings.app and change it if needed.

Comment: @rckoenes Thanks for your time! I'm not sure if that is exactly the same case, as when asking for the user permissions each time with different types in the set prompting this view and allowing the user to change his previous choices in addition(!) to the new ones. I'll update the question with this info as it might be not clear...

Comment: Is it possible to detect authorization state from settings app rather than Healthkit.app? I mean can I show the healthkit authorization in settings.app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By design, it is not possible to re-prompt the user for authorization.  If you would like the user to consider changing their authorizations for your app, ask them to go to Settings or the Health app to do so.

Answer (score 1):

By the time being we can't do it. However, it makes sense to be able to do so because switching the access rights is not as simple as tap the "ok" or "cancel" button. You may assume that everyone knows how to tap the switch and turn things on, but trust me, you'll be wrong if you assume that way.

I'd file a bug in apple's radar to let them know that their design is not flawless. We should be able to prompt the user again. If user is annoyed, he can always delete our app, and I feel it's much better than reading a really long "how to enable the access in Health.app" list and getting confused, and that's what a normal user would do.

Comment: by saying "We should be able to prompt the user again." you are going against the Apple Eco System. If the user denies. That should be the final decision and developer should accept. Although if you really can't work without the permission just ask the user to allow from settings and restrict the functionality you're offering.

Comment: I think I made myself quite clear. Of course I'm against Apple's decision on this matter, I'm an iOS developer doesn't mean that I'm an Apple fanboy that blindly accept everything Apple said.